# android:imeOptions="actionNext" does not go to the next EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, imeoptions

I have encountered a strange behaviour of `android:imeOptions="actionNext"`. When I press next on the keyboard it actually navigates out of the AutoCompleteEditText but doesn't focus on the next one. I am using the same setting for my other EditTexts and it works fine.

Here is the .xml code:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/login_form_height"
    android:hint="@string/prompt_email_username"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:padding="@dimen/login_form_padding" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/login_form_height"
    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
    android:imeActionId="6"
    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:padding="@dimen/login_form_padding" />
```

So when I press next it leaves "@+id/email" but doesn't focus on "@+id/password".
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`android:singleLine="true"` or `android:inputType="text"` can solve your problem

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/login_form_height"
    android:hint="@string/prompt_email_username"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:padding="@dimen/login_form_padding" />
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The thing is I use the same .xml code for other views and it works just fine. Could it be an issue with AutoCompleteTextView?